# Config Swagger-ui path

Tags: java, swagger, quarkus

I'm config swagger-ui path from this context below using yml file and using quarkus

> swagger-ui:
> path: /clinic/swagger-ui

but when start my application and access swagger can't see the page swagger-ui and changing the configuration as bellow, i can see the page swagger-ui when I change it back to the above configuration I can see the swagger-ui.

> swagger-ui:
> path: /swagger-ui

I do this and it works during local execution if it stops and restart my application I have to redo the same steps that I described above.
Is the any solution for me not to need this? Because I have a rule which I must follow where the rest of the routes and endpoint's rest must be inside /clinic as below

> /clinic/swagger-ui -> page swagger
>
> /clinic/api/ -> endpoints rest's

Answer (score 1):

This works following the [Quarkus guide for OpenAPI and Swagger UI](https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui). To reproduce, I did the following:

1. Create a Quarkus (1.8.1) project with the following extensions:

   - `quarkus-smallrye-openapi`
   - `quarkus-config-yaml` (for your `application.yml`)
   - `quarkus-resteasy` (for programming REST services)
   - `quarkus-resteasy-jsonb`
2. Create your REST endpoint (I just did the `/fruits` example of the aforementioned guide)
3. Configure `application.yml`

```yml
quarkus:
    smallrye-openapi:
        path: /fruit/openapi
    swagger-ui:
        path: /fruit/swagger-ui
        always-include: true
```

Now you can access the OpenAPI yml via `curl http://localhost:8080/fruit/openapi` and the Swagger UI by pointing your browser to `http://localhost:8080/fruit/swagger-ui`.

**Please note** that the setting `always-include: true` makes the Swagger UI available even in production!